# Retrofit2, Android, @Get Parsing for the Array of Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, retrofit, retrofit2

I am parsing the title correctly and displaying it in a listview. I cant seem to access the

```
String findMe;
```

seen below. Here are the two objects, sample response and my call.

response pojo:

```
public class Response {
     public String count;
     public  Result []results;
}
```

first object

```
public class Result {
     public String title;
     public static arr [] Details;
```

second object

```
public class Details   {
     public Integer _id;
     public String findMe;
}
```

response:

```
Call<Response> call = api.getListWith(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
            result = response.body();
}
```

I am getting the title just by passing 'result' into the adapter and using

`result[i].getTitle();`

I tried using
`result[i].Details[0].findMe;`

but my error response is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
```

Comment: Remove the static in the `Result` class. Also better declare arrays as collections such as `List`

Comment: have you properly initialized the `results` array or `Details`?

Comment: Why should I remove that class? I am getting the title from it.

Comment: They are  a null object reference, so it is there but I am not setting it.

Comment: You should initialize them with instances of their default constructors

Comment: You are asking a question about deserializing something into your java classes. You didn't tell us anything about what serialization library or data format you are using. Retrofit2 is just an abstraction over http and the conversion to java classes. Can you provide what the raw data looks like(JSON, SOAP, XML?)  as well as what library you are using to deserialize(Jackson, Gson, moshi)?

Comment: I am using Gson to deserialize some JSON nested objects. Details is nested in Result.

Comment: Can you post the correct POJO class with annotations? And also the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Result {
    public String title;
    public Details[] arr;
}
```

Then

```
results[i].getarr[0].getfindMe();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but this wasn't my problem.  I was making the wrong api call. For anyone that is interested - I just checked using with:                      String s = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
Log.v(TAG, s);